# How to put a negative (<0) RGB color values to an image in PIL?

Tags: python, image, compression, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a kind of delta encoding task for school and I need to put the difference between consequtive pixels into next pixels just so I decode them later. Unfortunately, if the difference is negative PIL function putdata will somehow convert the value to 0 which makes it impossible for me to decode it later using an inverse filter. What could I do to make it possible? Note that encoded image doesn't have to look nice, it just has to contain the data needed for me to decode it.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("lena.bmp")
img = img.convert("RGB")
encoded_img = Image.new("RGB", (img.size[0], img.size[1]))
decoded_img = Image.new("RGB", (img.size[0], img.size[1]))
colorlist = []
pixels = []

# Encoding
img.show()

for pixel in img.getdata():

    R0 = pixel[0]
    G0 = pixel[1]
    B0 = pixel[2]
    colorlist.append(R0)
    colorlist.append(G0)
    colorlist.append(B0)

    if len(colorlist) > 3:
        R0 -= colorlist[len(colorlist) - 6]
        G0 -= colorlist[len(colorlist) - 5]
        B0 -= colorlist[len(colorlist) - 4]

    pixels.append((R0, G0, B0))

encoded_img.putdata(pixels)
encoded_img.show()
encoded_img.save("encoded.bmp")
```

Comment: You could use an intermediate intensity as baseline, instead of zero.

Comment: In other words map -127...127 to 0..255. Also note that PIL supports `"I"` (32-bit signed integer pixels) and `"F"` (32-bit floating point pixels) _single_ channel image [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes), so perhaps you could use three of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulo 256 for each of the `R`, `G`, `B` values. That means that all values end up in range [0-255], i.e. one byte, e.g. -1 maps to 255.

Then, for two *R* values `R0` and `R1`, their difference would be:

```
Rdiff = (R0 - R1) % 256
```

Later on, you can do the inverse:

```
R0 = (R1 + Rdiff) % 256
```

The calculation will be correct as long as all inputs are also in range 0-255 (which they are, in this case).

These are some sample encoded (`Rdiff`) values, with that logic:

```
R0=50, R1=20  --> Rdiff=30
R0=10, R1=50  --> Rdiff=216
R0=0,  R1=5   --> Rdiff=251
R0=33, R1=200 --> Rdiff=89
```